# Can't remove blank characters/white lines after json decode and extraction

Tags: php, json, curl, whitespace

im trying to remove the blank characters (they look like a the space key has been spammed - for about 1 - 2 lines) This is my function

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com/a-good-coffee");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
//sleep(6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "blablabla123abc");
$func = curl_exec($ch);
//$func will return this :
//{ "id": "great_coffee", "object": "amazing", "buff": google }
$data = json_decode($func);

echo $rem = $data-id;

//every time if after the $func is being used the id randomizes
//great_coffee will be good_things
//im okay with that but actually
//good_things will have a lot of white lines, blank characters (it looks like a lot of space has been spammed for about 1-2 lines)
```

**The output for $rem** is `good_things                                                      "` 
It has a lot of spacing so i tried str_replace and preg_replace but they had no effect.

*also there is no " in the $rem output, i just added it so i can demonstrate how much whitespace is here*

**expected output**:`good_things`

Comment: Have you tried using `trim()`?

Comment: yes i did try using trim but the result is the same with whitespacing

Comment: Have you tried trim on `$rem` variable or on `$data` variable?

Comment: i tried trim on both

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

Those space might be other non-printables in a human-readable way. I suggest you use `echo addcslashes('foo[ ]', 'A..z');` to find them and take the necessary steps.